# Object of two pages are changing eachother?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within my Blazor Server project I have one page and one Mudblazor Dialog. On this page I list all `activities` and if you click on one `activity` it activates the Mudblazor Dialog. Since I did not find any methods to pass data to this dialog, I made a `StateContainer` to pass the activity from the page to the dialog.

However, when I edit a value of the `activity` within the dialog, it also changes on the page. How is this possible? Are these two connected via the `StateContainer`?

**On page and dialog I inject the StateContainer:**

```
@inject StateContainer stateContainer
```

**Code on page to open dialog and update `StateContainer`**:

```
private void OpenActivity(Activity activity)
{
    stateContainer.SetActivityValue(activity);
    var options = new DialogOptions { MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Medium, FullWidth = true };
    DialogService.Show<ShowActivity_Dialog>(activity.Name, options);
}
```

**Code of Dialog:**

```
private Activity _activity;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (DataLoading)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        DataLoading = true;

        var activity = stateContainer.Activity;
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    finally
    {
        DataLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `catch (Exception) { throw; }`?

Comment: This is basic dotnet behaviour. Look up "C# reference types"

Comment: When you pass a reference to an object (e.g. `Activity`)-- all consumers of that object are sharing the same instance.  If you want a new object with the same information, you have to go through the trouble of `new()`-ing an object and mapping all the properties of the old object to the new one, e.g. `Activity newActivity = new(){ ID = oldActivity.ID, Text = oldActivity.Text}`  Otherwise, any changes you make to the shared object will be reflected all over the place (which is sometimes a very useful feature).

Comment: As eluded to above.   You are passing around references to the same object.  You're editing the same object in the edit form as in the list.  Your application design is too simplistic.  You need to rethink your data pipeline.  How to you persist the data changes?

Comment: Okay, now I know why this is happening. Anyone any tips on how to solve this or to make the data pipeline better?

Comment: Search Blazor CRUD and you will find any number of online tutorials on the subject.  They all have their pluses and minuses.  Once you have the basics you can read this article of mine that shows how to develop a composite generic data pipeline - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5350000/A-Different-Repository-Pattern-Implementation.

Comment: Thanks! basic CRUD is no problem for me. I'll look at your article. Do you have an example project for Visual Studio I can take a look at?

Comment: If you have any other articles, example projects and/or tutorials that could be useful for me, please send those aswell! I'm quite new to blazor server and looking forward to learn more about anything... SignalR/Hubs, project structures, dialog's I use with MudBlazor etc.